# Can you run embedded Java Applets on a Windows Phone browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, applet, windows-phone

I am doing research on browser technology compatabillity and I can not seem to find out if one is able to run an embedded Java Applet on the Windows Phone's browser (IE). Do anyone know the answer for this, or know a source that does?

I would test it myself, but I do not have an Windows Phone available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java Applets are not supported on Windows Phone.  I went to the [Java test page](http://java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp) on my Lumia 920 running Windows Phone 8 and the applet didn't run.